# How do you simulate awk in python, for multiline output?

Tags: python

I am used to have awk to retrieve a column from a file.

I need to do something similar now in python. At the moment I use a subprocess and save the result in a variable.

Is possible to run something similar to awk in python, without write a lot of code? I was looking at split; but I don't get how do you parse trough multiple lines.

The input that I have is similar to a simple ls -la or netstat -r. I would like to get the 3rd column, so I can do what I would do with

```
awk '{print $3}'
```

Example of the source:

```
a    b    c    d    e
1    2    4    5    2
X    Y    Z    S    R
```

The shortest that I can think of, is a loop splitting for each line, then split each line in single string, print the string[2]. But I am not sure how to write this in the simplest and shortest way; as short as write the awk command in a subprocess.

Comment: Look into [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, using [pythonpy](https://github.com/Russell91/pythonpy)

```
rtb@bartek-laptop ~ $ cat tmp
a    b    c    d    e
1    2    4    5    2
X    Y    Z    S    R
rtb@bartek-laptop ~ $ cat tmp | py -x "x.split()[2]"
c
4
Z
```

Or in script

```
with open('tmp') as f:
    result = [line.split()[2] for line in f]
    # now result contains list ['c', '4', 'Z']
```

Comment: Awesome; so I do not have to divide each line and then each string with split? I see that you just call string.split()[2] and it return the whole column at $3

Comment: You do have to split each line. `pythonpy` does the for loop over lines for you, and the script contains a for loop over lines inside list comprehension (**`for line in f`**). Good news is: awk surely contains some loop over lines too.